# how do you generate Delphi output with ANTLR?

Tags: delphi, antlr

How do you generate Delphi output with ANTLR?

My grammar outputs ok in other languages but there seems I'm doing something wrong since I'm getting an error.

There is special switches or something to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "I'm getting an error" is useless without the *specific* error you're getting. You need to post the exact error, the grammar you're using, and the command line you're using at a minimum if you want to get an answer. As is, this question will most likely be closed as not being a real question. Please remember that we can't see your screen from here, and so the only information we have to go on is what you give us in your question.

Comment: Do you have a code generation target for Delphi? I don't see one listed on http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets

Comment: @Mason: there is this: http://www.antlr.org/depot/antlr3/release-3.1.3/runtime/Delphi/README.TXT (not that I've used it).

Comment: Someone have done it early in 2008 (ANTLR For Delphi Target): Head [here](http://www.sqlitedeveloper.com/five-minute-introduction-antlr-delphi-target).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably encountering an error like:

> error(10):  internal error: Exprtoken.g : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Can't find template actionGate.st; group hierarchy is [Delphi]

AFAIK, the `Delphi` target has always been experimental, and hasn't been updated in the past few years: I don't recommend you use it.

Comment: [ANTLR For Delphi Target](http://www.sqlitedeveloper.com/five-minute-introduction-antlr-delphi-target) seems to be appealing.

Comment: @menjaraz, the first sentence on that page *"After registering , You can get a download link of Antlr For Delphi Target."* turned me off. Also, when looking at the instructions on that page, it still needs ANTLR 2.7, which is rather old: not something I'd recommend using. However, if one absolutely **must** generate a Delphi parser, it could be worth trying, of course.

Comment: So why not give a try to **tkoskine**'s antlr-3.1 on [here](https://bitbucket.org/tkoskine/antlr-3.1/src). More up to date and  including a *Delphi Code generator and Runtime library* by Erik van Bilsen (A great great Delphi contributor by the way ! I appreciate much his Ribbon component ).

Comment: @menjaraz, I won't be able to try anything with Delphi: I'm not familiar with the language, and I'm not running Windows.

Comment: I'm not either familiar with Antlr, I'm just beginning to harness GoldParser using Delphi and Digital Mars D2. Thank you taking time to answer my comments. Hopefully they are helpfull for the SO community.

Comment: @menjaraz, no problem. When using Delphi, GoldParser seems to be the better options, IMO. I've not used it myself, but heard good stories about it.